# Как отрисовать N изображений React + Spring Boot

Tags: reactjs, spring, axios, useeffect, usestate

Встал вопрос - как отрисовать N картинок, если Spring может возвращать из метода только одно изображение? У меня был запрос на получение имени файлом, но никак не получалось вернуть именно нужное количество изображений. Я нашёл решение и захотел им поделиться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала создадим метод, который будет отправлять нам список названий файлов:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getTrophies/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ArrayList<TrophiesDTO>> getTrophies(@PathVariable String id) throws IOException {
        if (!playerRepository.existsByNick(id))
            throw new AppException("Неизвестный пользователь", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

        PlayerDoc playerDoc = playerRepository.findByNick(id).get(0);
        ArrayList<String> trophies = playerDoc.getTrophies();

        ArrayList<TrophiesDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String trophy : trophies){
            list.add(new TrophiesDTO(trophy));
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(list);
    }
```

Теперь создадим метод, который будет возвращать нам изображение:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getImage/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFile(@PathVariable String id) throws IOException {
        String path = "";
        if (fileRepository.existsByFileName(id))
            path = fileRepository.findByFileName(id).get(0).getLink();
        else throw new AppException("Неизвестный параметр", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

        String mediaType = getMediaType(path);

        File file = new File(imageDirectory + path);

        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentLength(fileContent.length).contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(mediaType)).body(fileContent);
    }


    private String getMediaType(String path){
        String extension = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("."));

        return switch (extension) {
            case ".png" -> "image/png";
            case ".jpg" -> "image/jpg";
            case ".jpeg" -> "image/jpeg";
            case ".webp" -> "image/webp";
            case ".svg" -> "image/svg+xml";
            default -> "";
        };
    }
```

На React'е я использовал `axios`: `npm install axios`

Создадим функцию, которая будет отвечать за запросы:

```js
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8084/";
axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
const request = (method, url, data, headers={}, responseType="") =>{
    if (responseType !== ""){
        return axios({
            method: method,
            headers: headers,
            url: url,
            data: data,
            responseType: 'blob'
        });
    }
    return axios({
        method: method,
        headers: headers,
        url: url,
        data: data
    });
};
```

Также потребуются `useState` и `useEffect`.

Оставшаяся часть кода, где мы вызываем `useState` и нужную функцию в нём:

```js
    function getElemByValue(arr, value, key) {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
            if (arr[i][key] === value){
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    const getTrophies = () => {
        request("GET", "/getTrophies/" + params.id, {}, {"Accept": "application/json","Content-Type": "application/json"}).then((resp) =>{
            resp.data.map((trophy) =>{
                getTrophiesImg(resp.data, trophy);
            });
        });
    }

    const getTrophiesImg = (arr, trophy) => {
        request("GET", "/getImage/" + trophy.alt, {}, {"Content-Type": "image/jpeg"}, "blob").then((resp) =>{
            let temp = arr;
            temp[getElemByValue(temp, trophy.alt, "alt")]["src"] = URL.createObjectURL(resp.data);
            setTrophies(temp);
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getTrophies();
    }, []);
```

Также я использовал `useParams`, чтоб получить параметр из адреса:

```js
const params = useParams()
```